# Filter processes by command name in Linux

Tags: linux, ps

How do I filter based on command name? For example, find commands with the text "python". This is what I have now, which doesn't filter:

```
 ps -u my_user -o pid,rss,command | awk '{print $0}{sum+=$2} END {print "Total", sum/1024, "MB"}'
```

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. Added

```
| grep text_i_want
```

to the end.

Comment: you can add /text_i_want/ in front of the awk rules; like
`awk '/text_i_want/ {print; sum+=$2} END {print "total " sum}'`